# Is there any solution for deploying of site on wordpress with automated adding it to Google Search Console and Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, wordpress

Is there any solution for deploying of site on wordpress with automated adding it to Google Search Console and Google Analytics via APIs (using html file for approving)? Sometime I need deploy up to 3-5 sites with routine operations like described above and it takes a very long time.

Answer (score 2):

### Google Analytics

You can use the [Google Analytics Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/?hl=en) to create a [property](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/insert?hl=en) or a [view/profile](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles?hl=en).

#### Google Search Console

Sadly, the [Google Search Console API](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/) only allows you to check data. Nevertheless, keep an eye at [Google Site Verification API](https://developers.google.com/site-verification/v1/getting_started). As far as I know, right now you can only get access to previously created properties but there's been a while since the last time I checked and they are getting new beta versions. Maybe in a while, you could manage everything through there.